# Erro de mime type no uso de css dinâmico

Tags: php, css, laravel, vue.js

Exibe a mensagem abaixo ao tentar aplicar a folha de estilo, porém ela está sendo exibida sem erros:

**because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.**

Answer (score -3):

Postei esta pergunta apenas para compartilhar a solução que encontrei pois tive que garimpar muito para resolver esse problema simples.

a solução foi adicionar headers abaixo, na verdade o problema se concentra apenas no X-Content-Type-Options, que o nginx adiciona o header text/html pra tudo que ele serve que nao tem header definido.

```
header_remove();
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public');
header('Expires: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 86400));
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
header("X-Content-Type-Options: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
```

Todavia adicionei estes headers por considerar o ideal.